# best way to get minimal distance between offsets

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, jquery-ui

I am making a text draggable and it should be inserted on one input depending on its distance between the inputs and the final position of the text dragged, see example :

```js
$('span').draggable({
opacity: 0.7,
helper: "clone",
stop: function(){
            var offset = $('.ui-draggable-dragging').offset();
            var xFinalPos = offset.left;
            var yFinalPos = offset.top;
            
        }
})
```

```css
 span {
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer
}
div {
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-left:100px;
}
input {
  margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<span class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">Text</span>
<div>
<input id="input1" type="text">
<input id="input2" type="text">
<input id="input3" type="text">
<input id="input4" type="text">
<input id="input5" type="text">
<input id="input6" type="text">
</div>
```

What I did so far is to get the final position of the dragged text xFinalPos and yFinalPos, my question what is the best way to get the minimal distance between offsets. My final goal is to print dragged text on the closest input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to count distances. jQuery UI already does it for you:

```js
$('#draggable').draggable({
  opacity: 0.7,
  helper: "clone"
});

$( ".input-grid" ).droppable({
  accept: "#draggable",
  tolerance: "intersect",
  classes: {
    "ui-droppable-hover": "active"
  },
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $("input", this).val($(ui.helper).text());
  }
});
```

```css
span {
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer
}
.content {
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-left:50px;
}
.input-grid {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}
.input-grid.active > input {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<span id="draggable" class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">Text</span>
<div class="content">
  <div class="input-grid">
    <input id="input1" class="dock" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="input-grid">
    <input id="input2" class="dock" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="input-grid">
    <input id="input3" class="dock" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="input-grid">
    <input id="input4" class="dock" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="input-grid">
    <input id="input5" class="dock" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="input-grid">
    <input id="input6" class="dock" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```